# dll in Eclipse build path giving error

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

I have imported java web/standalone projects to my workspace. These projects I have received from other vendor. Some of the projects contains the WinPerfMon.dll in the class path/build path. And its giving error as -

"Archive for required library: 'WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/WinPerfMon.dll in project 'ConsoleAdmin_ECM' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file"

And I am not able to compile the project due to the above mentioned error.

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: @JqueryLearner I don't think that's the same issue.

Comment: @RobinGreen I am sorry if its not related.removing my close vote

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `WinPerfMon.dll` from the build path and copy it to `C:\WINDOWS\system32` on the system(s) on which you will do performance monitoring of the application.

Comment: Actually I would like to get it compiled with same configuration as shared with me in exported project which I have received. The project imported has no other issues except this dll one. So I am not understanding why the successful project export has giving error in my workspace. Presently I am not worried about the run-time issue with dll.